# LiDAR data processing - Which is best Python or R?

Tags: python, r, geoprocessing, lidar, library

I have started working with LiDAR data processing recently. I looked up for libraries to work with LiDAR in Python and R. I would like to know which one has better libraries and extensive documentation to work with LiDAR.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. This site requires you to ask specific problems. Kindly take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for guidelines. You can search google or any literature for this.